# Copying Definitions from Wikipedia to a Crossword game

Tags: copyright

i have a crossword android mobile game that is published on playstore. it's monetized by ads.

because this is a crossword game, i need a lot of words and it's definition. Currently it has 300+ level. I took most of the definition (about 95%+) from a dictionary (i have seek permission from them) and some are from Wikipedia.

Sometime the word definition from wikipedia is too long so i make it shorter, by cutting some word or replace it.

in credits section of the game, i provide the link to wikipedia.org. i cant provide link to each wikipedia page because there would be so many, and i don't remember all of them.

Will this be alright ? Is the definition in wikipedia count as fact or not?

I mean, i know Wikipedia won't sue me or something like that, and i don't live in US. But my OCD made my question a lot about license.

Comment: OCD sufferer or a perfectionist? There's a difference, a **big** difference.  If the former, then I feel your pain brother. If the latter, then please don't disrespect genuine suffers.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia content can be copied, modified, and redistributed if and only if the copied version is made available on the same terms to others and acknowledgment of the authors of the Wikipedia article used is included (a link back to the article is generally thought to satisfy the attribution requirement; click the link for more details). Copied Wikipedia content will therefore remain free under an appropriate license and can continue to be used by anyone subject to certain restrictions, most of which aim to ensure that freedom. This principle is known as copyleft in contrast to typical copyright licenses.

You can find their copyright terms here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights

Comment: Nothwithstanding the above, a short definition of a term, such as used in a crossword puzzle, is probably not even copyrightable.

Comment: Well of course, everything on Wikipedia is common knowledge but it's still best to give credit.